# Parsing a String of Zip Codes with PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am moving my company from a legacy service to a new system.  I have written some conversion utilities in PHP to facilitate the move.  One issue I am coming accross is converting the zip codes.

In the old system, Zips could be mixed in one line:

```
700,701,30518,30511,30000-30010,400,30097,30101-30201
```

In my new system, each type of zip must be broken into it's own line:

```
700,701,400
30518,30511,30097
30000-30010,30101-30201
```

So I need to import the first code block and output the second code block to 3 variables.  I am working in PHP.  Any Guidance?  The order of the zips is random.  I'm Lost.

Comment: Is `700` shorthand for `00700`?

Comment: No, it's shorthand for 70000-70099

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is what I got:

```
/(\d+)(-\d+)?/s
```

`/s` is to ignore newlines.

```
<?php

$subject = "700,701,400\n30518,30511,30097\n30000-30010,30101-30201\n";

preg_match_all("/(\d+)(-\d+)?/s", $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);

?>
```

Here's output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 700
    [1] => 701
    [2] => 400
    [3] => 30518
    [4] => 30511
    [5] => 30097
    [6] => 30000-30010
    [7] => 30101-30201
)
```

Alternatively, you can do this:

```
$arr = explode("\n", $subject);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
    preg_match_all("/(\d+)(-\d+)?/s", $arr[$i], $matches);
    print_r($matches[0]);
}
```

If there's only three types, then you can just `preg_match` for each line.

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 700
    [1] => 701
    [2] => 400
)
Array
(
    [0] => 30518
    [1] => 30511
    [2] => 30097
)
Array
(
    [0] => 30000-30010
    [1] => 30101-30201
)
Array
(
)
```

Comment: This looks like what I need.  Thank you so much for the quick response.  I will try it tomorrow when I get to work.  I'll post my results here.

Comment: @user1499521 There are regex sites like `regexer` and `regexpal` that allow you to test things like this, which prompted my quick response. You don't have to -wait- until you get to work when you can reproduce it yourself.